# Condicional al recorrer un array siempre se queda en el primero

Tags: php, javascript, array, bucle-for

Estoy luchando con algo que parece facil pero no logro concretarlo.

tengo un array

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'discount' => string '5' (length=1)
      'min_qty' => int 200
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'discount' => string '15' (length=2)
      'min_qty' => int 500
```

del cual quiero hacer comprobaciones al recorrelo en javascript y mostrar un texto

```
var array_disc = '<?php echo json_encode($disc); ?>';
var discounts_by = JSON.parse(array_disc);

for (const index in discounts_by) {

    var minimum_qty = discounts_by[index].min_qty;
    var discount_porcentaje = discounts_by[index].discount;

    // this.value va cambiando porque se toma de $('[name=quantity]').change(function()...
    if (this.value >= minimum_qty) {
        // si es mayor o igual muestro un texto
        $('#product_total_price').html('tiene ' + discount_porcentaje + '% de descuento');
    }else{
        // sino muestro un texto
        $('#product_total_price').html('no hay descuento');
    }
}
```

el problema es que siempre me toma el primero que recorre y queda ahi, osea toma el minimo 200 y cuando paso los 500 el descuento siempre es el de 5% (que es para la cantidad minima de 200) pero deberia ser el de 15% ya que esta pasando los 500. :(

gracias!!!!

**Actualizacion:**
al parecer era por el `}else{` que no dejaba seguir las comprobaciones al recorrer el array, retirarndo el "`else`" se soluciono el problema!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No veo nada mal en tu código. Lo he recreado metiendolo todo en un bucle for para emular un cambio en el valor *this.value* y en lugar de mostrar distintos textos en una misma caja, he hecho que se vayan agregando los textos se que muestran, y el resultado ha sido que entra y hace bien ambos casos.

Quizás deberías mirar que el valor *this.value* esté llegando correctamente, que se esté mostrando de la forma que tu quieres,...

```js
var discounts_by = [{'discount':5,'min_qty':200},{'discount':15,'min_qty':500}];

for(var value = 0; value < 550; value++){

for (const index in discounts_by) {

    var minimum_qty = discounts_by[index].min_qty;
    var discount_porcentaje = discounts_by[index].discount;

    // this.value va cambiando porque se toma de $('[name=quantity]').change(function()...
    if (value >= minimum_qty) {
        // si es mayor o igual muestro un texto
        var div = $('<div>').text('tiene ' + discount_porcentaje + '% de descuento');
        $('#wrapper').append(div);
    }
}



}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">

</div>
```

Comment: Hola @cooper, hice la prueba como comentaste y tbm funciono!!, tenia un error ya que habia colocado el "}else{" no me di cuenta (debe ser la hora ya de ir a dormir ja) en el if (this.value >= minimum_qty){...} yo habia colocado luego un "else" y que mostrara otro texto, entonces parece que siempre paraba en el 5%, y ese "else" no hacia que llegara el 15%, en esa prueba del for que colocaste me di cuenta!